# How to identify newly added has_many association in rails after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Have below association in `author` class

```
has_many :books,
class_name :"Learning::Books",
through: :elearning,
dependent: :destroy
```

with after_commit as,

```
after_commit :any_book_added?, on: :update

def any_book_added?
     book = books.select { |book| book.previous_changes.key?('id') }
     # book's previous_changes is always empty hash even when newly added
end
```

Unable to find the newly added association with this method. Is this due to class_name?

Comment: Have you considered flipping this logic around and adding an `after_commit` on `book.rb` to tell the `author` which owns the `book` that a new book was added?

Comment: there is `after_add` for `has_many`: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

Comment: yes @yez. but i need it in author model along with other association changes.. 
JoshBrody it didn't work when I had where clause in association

Answer (score 4):

Rails has [a couple methods that might help you, `before_add` and `after_add`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/association_basics.html#association-callbacks)

Using this, you can define a method to set an instance variable to `true`

```rb
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, through: :elearning, after_add: :new_book_added

  def any_book_added?
    @new_book_added 
  end

  private

  def new_book_added
    @new_book_added = true
  end
end
```

Then when you add a book to an author, the `new_book_added` method will be called and you can at any future time ask your `Author` class if `any_book_added?`

i.e.

```rb
author = Author.last
author.any_book_added?
=> false
author.books = [Book.new]
author.any_book_added?
=> true
```

As you can see, the callback method `new_book_added` can accept the book that has been added as well so you can save that information.

Comment: @josh-brody pointed this out in the comment above, I just expanded on it.